# How to install Gazebo 9 in melodic using "packages.ros.org" as repository

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the official gazebo website (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install), the installation procedure from the repository "packages.osrfoundation.org" is given. But they have nowhere informed how to install it from "packages.ros.org" repository.

I am having trouble in installing gazebo from ""packages.osrfoundation.org"  in my ROS Melodic + Ubuntu 18.04.
Also in the official website (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions#InstallingGazebo), it is written "**do not use the osrfoundation repository.**".

So, what is the proper procedure to install Gazebo9 from "**packages.ros.org**" repository for ROS melodic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24020/how-to-install-gazebo-9-in-melodic--using-%22packages.ros.org%22-as-repository/) by [Hirak Basumatary](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17029/hirak-basumatary/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> I am having trouble in installing gazebo from ""packages.osrfoundation.org"

Can you describe the problem?

> it is written "do not use the osrfoundation repository.".

That wording it a bit too dramatic, it should be **you do not *need* to use the osrfoundation repository**.

> So, what is the proper procedure to install Gazebo9 from "packages.ros.org" repository

I think the tutorial is a bit misleading there too. Gazebo itself is only available from packages.ros.org for a [few platforms](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gazebo9/), which does not include Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.

I believe the tutorial may be mixing `gazebo` with `gazebo_ros_pkgs`. ROS Melodic gets [gazebo9 from Ubuntu official packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gazebo9), and [gazebo_ros_pkgs from packages.ros.org](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-pkgs/).

---

To summarize: you shouldn't be having any problems using `gazebo9` from packages.osrfoundation.org together with `ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-pkgs` from packages.ros.org.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hirak Basumatary](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17029/hirak-basumatary/) on 2019-10-23**:
While installing Melodic i did manage to open up Gazebo. But it did not contain the world files and other plugins in the folder "usr/share/gazebo-9" . So i deleted Gazebo and tried to install it again, then i got the problem of installing from "packages.osrfoundation.org". Is it because the server of "packages.osrfoundation.org" is down. It always gets stuck at - "waiting for headers" connecting to "packages.osrfoundation.org"

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-10-23**:
Interesting, I've never had the problem of the server taking too long to respond, but it may depend on location. You could try removing the osrfoundation packages from your system and install gazebo9 from Ubuntu's official repo. Just look up "how to remove a ppa".

**Comment by [Hirak Basumatary](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17029/hirak-basumatary/) on 2019-10-30**:
Thank You very much.. After deleting osrfoundation package from the system. It worked. IThe gazebo was installed fine. However some files were missing which i cloned from bitbucket source of osrfoundation gazebo